# In web3j, how do you create a TypeReference for array types discovered at runtime?

Tags: java, ethereum, web3-java

I'm trying to write a Java application with web3j that can read an arbitrary abi file, show the list of AbiDefinitions to the user and let him make a call to a constant function of his choice. How do I compute the outTypes below?

```
AbiDefinition functionDef = ...; // found at runtime  
List<Type> args = ...; // I know how to do this  
List<NamedType> outputs = functionDef.getOutputs(); // list of output parameters  
List<TypeReference<?>> outTypes = ????;  
Function function = new Function(functionDef.getName(), args, outTypes);
```

The TypeReference class uses tricks with generic types that work when the generic type is hardcoded in the source code like this:

```
new TypeReference.StaticArrayTypeReference< StaticArray< Int256>>(2){}
```

This is what the generated contract wrapper would do.

For simple types, I can do this:

```
Class<Type> type = (Class<Type>)AbiTypes.getType(typeName);
TypeReference<?> typeRef = TypeReference.create(type);
```

For array types like "int256[2]", what should I do?

Comment: Please show your code instead of trying to describe it.

Comment: I rewrote my question.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this? I'd also be curious how you generated that List<Type>.

Answer (score 1):

uniswapV2 router

function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts)

```
package com.test;

import org.web3j.abi.FunctionEncoder;
import org.web3j.abi.FunctionReturnDecoder;
import org.web3j.abi.TypeReference;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.DynamicArray;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Function;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Type;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256;
import org.web3j.protocol.Web3j;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.DefaultBlockParameterName;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.request.Transaction;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.EthCall;
import org.web3j.protocol.http.HttpService;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class main {
    private static String EMPTY_ADDRESS = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
    static Web3j web3j;
    static String usdt = "0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955";
    static String weth = "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c";
    static String pancakeRouter = "0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService("https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"));
        String s = web3j.netVersion().send().getNetVersion();
        System.out.println(s);
        List<BigInteger> list1 = getAmountsOut(usdt, weth);
        System.out.println("result::: ");
        for (BigInteger a : list1) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }

    public static List<BigInteger> getAmountsOut(String tokenInAddr, String tokenOutAddr) {
        String methodName = "getAmountsOut";
        String fromAddr = EMPTY_ADDRESS;
        List<Type> inputParameters = new ArrayList<Type>();
        Uint256 inAmount = new Uint256(new BigInteger("1000000000000000000"));
        Address inAddr = new Address(tokenInAddr);
        Address outAddr = new Address(tokenOutAddr);
        DynamicArray<Address> addrArr = new DynamicArray<Address>(inAddr, outAddr);

        inputParameters.add(inAmount);
        inputParameters.add(addrArr);

        List<TypeReference<?>> outputParameters = new ArrayList<TypeReference<?>>();
        TypeReference<DynamicArray<Uint256>> oa = new TypeReference<DynamicArray<Uint256>>() {
        };
        outputParameters.add(oa);

        Function function = new Function(methodName, inputParameters, outputParameters);
        String data = FunctionEncoder.encode(function);
        Transaction transaction = Transaction.createEthCallTransaction(fromAddr, pancakeRouter, data);

        EthCall ethCall;
        try {
            ethCall = web3j.ethCall(transaction, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).sendAsync().get();
            List<Type> results = FunctionReturnDecoder.decode(ethCall.getValue(), function.getOutputParameters());
            System.out.println(results);
            List<BigInteger> resultArr = new ArrayList<>();
            if (results.size() > 0) {
                for (Type tt : results) {
                    DynamicArray<Uint256> da = (DynamicArray<Uint256>) tt;
                    List<Uint256> lu = da.getValue();
                    if (lu.size() > 0) {
                        for (Uint256 n : lu) {
                            resultArr.add((BigInteger) n.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
                return resultArr;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `makeTypeReference` static method. It lets you create references like `create`, but it also accepts arrays.

The input parameter is the solidity type, the same used in the smart contract.

Example:
**uint256** for a single item; **uint256[]** for *n* items from uint256.

Usage:

```
TypeReference<?> typeReference = TypeReference.makeTypeReference("uint256[]");
```